# Highcharts / Highstock step line with gaps?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have a step line with gaps? I'm talking about the square wave kind of line (step line) that would have gaps?

This kind of line (at least in my case) is drawn from such a dataset that has the start time and the new value (level) as one data point. For example can I set NULL to be a level to achieve gaps in the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just add null point when you need a gap. Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mCLpr/

```
    series: [{
        data: [1,2,3,4,null,6,7,null,9],
        step: 'right',
        name: 'Right'
    }]
```

Comment: When the step us `center` I would like the line before/after `null` to continue to its full width and not cut after the point.

Is that possible?

Comment: All available options are listed in my demo above. Step only controls where threshold should be rendered (on the left point, in the middle or on the right point).

Comment: Pawel, thank you. But I would like the second series (with `step: "center"`) to draw the full step line before `null` point, and not stop at the point. Is that possible?

Comment: There's no option to control that. You can however create a plugin that wraps `getGraphPath` method and modify the logic there.