# Highcharts step line with gaps and series like [x,y]

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to generate a line plot in Highcharts similar to this:

```
|---------------|
     |-----|
          |--------------|
                                    |-------|
                                        |------|
```

A sample series data has the following shape:

```
[{"name":"AA01", "data": [[1423102786000,37],[1423102786000,37],[1423124408000,118],[1423124408000,118],[1423139198000,0],[1423139198000,0],[1423139305000,0],[1423139305000,0],[1423139305000,48],[1423139305000,48],[1423142136000,15],[1423142136000,15],[1423147902000,37],[1423147902000,37],[1423153292000,0],[1423153292000,0],[1423461724000,43],[1423461724000,43],[1423461724000,89],[1423461724000,89],[1423461724000,52],[1423461724000,52],[1423461724000,4],[1423461724000,4],[1423461724000,5],[1423461724000,5],[1423480654000,10],[1423480654000,10],[1423480953000,0],[1423480953000,0]]}]
```

The x axis is an integer while the y axis is a date. As you can see, all data points go in pairs to get the above layout: the value in y axis is two consecutives times the same, while it changes only in the x axis date.
I've followed some links to achieve this with no success:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243386/highcharts-highstock-step-line-with-gaps)

[Link2](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/line-step/)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516683/highstocks-line-missing-but-data-is-there)

As you can see, the main difference between these examples and my code is that I don't have a fixed categories axis, and that forces me to add the series data as `[x,y]` pairs.
I've tried things like `[x,null]`, `[null,null]` and just `null` but all of them produced unexpected results, mainly with the x axis labels (showing as initial label `01-01-1970`) and zooming problems (when I zoom on an area with points it suddenly appears on around `01-01-1970`). This makes me think that Highcharts is assuming `01-01-1970` when a date is null, which messes the entire chart. This is my code, although it's quite simple anyway:

```
function plot(unit, data) {
                $("#chart" + unit).highcharts({
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'xy'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: unit
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Date'
                        },
                        type: 'datetime',
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
                            rotation: 45,
                            align: 'left'
                        },
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Event number'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + convertDate(new Date(this.x)) + '</b><br/>' +
                                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                        }
                    },
                    //plotOptions: {},
                    series: data
                });
            }//END_FUNCTION
```

Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you're saying your data doesn't work well when shaped as `[x, y]` pairs but it seems to me that each point has 2 pieces of data: date (x) and that other integer (y). I remember that Highcharts needs to be specifically told whether your X axis is made up of categorical buckets (like nominal variables) or a continuous line (like dates or a number range, where many or most "ticks" on the line won't have a data point present for them). It sounds like your use case needs the latter. Have you looked into Highcharts' documentation to learn about the difference?

Take a look at this example chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time/grid and in the source code, note the following designation for the X axis:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
},
```

Also note that when you scroll down to the data points defined for that chart (still in the source), you can see they had to specifically create a JS Date object for every single data point. Since your date intervals are irregular, you'll probably have to do the same thing:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
  // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
  // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
  // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
  data: [
      [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
```

How to set up a Gantt chart in Highcharts is a whole different matter. I don't have experience with this but I've seen elegant examples online, so hopefully this won't pose as much trouble.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the code to my question, so you can see that I was already using the xAxis datetime type. Regarding your last suggestion, do you mean using a different series for each interval? It's not an ideal solution but it is definetely worth trying. I'll make some tests and then let you know. I've also been searching about specific Gantt charts for Highcharts and it seems there is something I could use, although I haven't checked it thoroughly. I'll post something else when I've done more tests.

Comment: @Hauri I'm not clear on the ideal structure for your data, I'm just throwing out suggestions based on how I've seen others configure Highcharts. But I do think that it would be a good starting point for you to just copy & paste another chart's data definitions (like the one I linked to and partially-quoted above), and define the data points inline rather than passing in a `data` object. This gives you a chance to play with different configurations quickly and more quickly figure out the shape your data object needs to take. Does that make sense?

Comment: I followed your advise and I got the chart I wanted. You're right as well suggesting to first make some tests with inline points instead of a data object. Just for you all to know the final result, my object data contains the following structure (sample): `series: [{"color":"#FF5050", "data": [{"marker":{"symbol":"triangle"}, "x":1423102786000, "y":37}, {"marker":{"symbol":"circle"},"x":1423119940000,"y":37}]},
                  {"color":"#FF5050", "data": [{"marker":{"symbol":"triangle"}, "x":1423102786000, "y":37}, {"marker":{"symbol":"circle"},"x":1423119940000,"y":37}]}]`

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked! When in doubt, I'll usually eliminate as many variables as possible and play around in a more "artificial" environment, then once I've figured out the basic structure needed I add in my variables in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

There is [user request](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) for adding Gantt charts to the Highcharts library. Try one of solutions posted there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to get the chart I wanted from a previous response, but I'm aware there are some possibilities to produce a real Gantt chart. Thanks anyway.